How do I install libavcodec58 on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS?
I have an extremely critical piece of software that depends on libavcodec58, but apparently this package is not available on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
How can I install this package?
~$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec58
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libavcodec58 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libavcodec58' has no installation candidate

~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble


Isn't this package part of ffmpeg?

To note, it's not very helpful to write "an extremely critical piece of software" without specifying what it is. Perhaps there is a way to get that software to use the newer libavcodec59.

Well, that piece of software is proprietary. Specifically, it's the Pleora eBUS SDK. Does that help?

Have you tried installing libavcodec59 (sudo apt-get install libavcodec59) and it didn't work with it? (in their documentation they wrire "For Ubuntu 18.04 install libavcodec57 & For Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 install libavcodec58", so maybe the same goes for newer versions install the newer version.)

"It's been dropped from Ubuntu 24.04/Mint 22, the current version is libavcodec60."
Please try to install version 60 and see if your critical piece of software.
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=434465
